# Is there a bug in Codingbat practice: Warmup-2 > string_match? Or what is wrong in my code?

Tags: python

> Practice question(link: https://codingbat.com/prob/p182414):
>
> Given 2 strings, a and b, return the number of the positions where
>   they contain the same length 2 substring. So "xxcaazz" and "xxbaaz"
>   yields 3, since the "xx", "aa", and "az" substrings appear in the same
>   place in both strings.
>
> string_match('xxcaazz', 'xxbaaz') → 3 string_match('abc', 'abc') → 2
>   string_match('abc', 'axc') → 0
>
> My code:

```
def string_match(a, b):
  lista = []
  listb = []
  for i in range(len(a)-1):
    itema = a[i:i+2]
    if itema not in lista:
      lista.append(itema)

  for i in range(len(b)-1):
    itemb = b[i:i+2]
    if itemb not in listb:
      listb.append(itemb)

  list=[]
  count = 0
  for item in lista:
    if item in listb and item not in list:
      list.append(item)
      count = count + 1

  return count
```

> Result: please see attached picture
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfz9U.png
>
> My question: for string_match('aabbccdd', 'abbbxxd'), shouldn't the
>   running result be 2 namely "ab" and "bb"?

Comment: *"My question: for string_match('aabbccdd', 'abbbxxd'), shouldn't the running result be 2 namely "ab" and "bb"?"*.. No, there's only "bb".

Comment: I got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, the two substrings have to be at the same index. i.e.:

"abcd" and "xabcd" will return 0, however,

"abdc" and "abcdc" will return 1 because "ab" in both strings are at the same index, but "dc" in both strings are at different indexes

Therefore, "aabbccdd" and "abbbxxd" will return only 1 because "ab" in both strings are at different indexes, but "bb" in both strings are at the same index

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it now, I missed the requirement of "in the place in both strings".